# How to specify dot of two RightAngleType types?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-plot,pst-func}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psset{PointSymbol=none}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,0,90}](0,0){A}(1,0){B}(0,1){C}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,0,90}](-1,-1){A'}(0,-1){B'}(-1,0){C'}
    \pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue, RightAngleType=suisseromand,RightAngleSize=1]{B}{A}{C}
    \pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue, RightAngleType=german,RightAngleSize=1]{B'}{A'}{C'}
    \psline(B)(A)(C)
    \psline(B')(A')(C')
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:

How to define the position of dot for `RightAngleType=suisseromand` and `RightAngleType=german` with `RightAngleSize=1` **BASED ON** the coordinate of three pairs A,B,C and A',B',C' ?

From [https://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-eucl/pst-eucl.tex](https://archiv.dante.de/%7Eherbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-eucl/pst-eucl.tex)

[image]

but, sorry, I don't understand it!

Comment: How about removing the dot altogether and then placing it yourself? Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w33FI.png) ([code](https://pastebin.com/raw/PHFS9RRP)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version 1.70 from https://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-eucl/pst-eucl.tex has an optional argument `RightAngleDotDistance` which is preset to `1` as a factor to the current distance which is `0.5` for a german and `0.45` for a swissromand angle. Setting it to another value than `1` the dot can be moved to or from the reference point:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psset{PointSymbol=none}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,0,90}](0.5,0.5){A}(1.5,0.5){B}(0.5,1.5){C}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,0,90}](-1,-1){A'}(0,-1){B'}(-1,0){C'}
    \pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue, RightAngleType=suisseromand,RightAngleSize=1]{B}{A}{C}
    \pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue, RightAngleType=german,RightAngleSize=1]{B'}{A'}{C'}
    \psline(B)(A)(C)
    \psline(B')(A')(C')
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psset{PointSymbol=none}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,0,90}](0.5,0.5){A}(1.5,0.5){B}(0.5,1.5){C}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,0,90}](-1,-1){A'}(0,-1){B'}(-1,0){C'}
    \pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue, RightAngleType=suisseromand,RightAngleSize=1,RightAngleDotDistance=1.25]{B}{A}{C}
    \pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue, RightAngleType=german,RightAngleSize=1,RightAngleDotDistance=1.5]{B'}{A'}{C'}
    \psline(B)(A)(C)
    \psline(B')(A')(C')
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]